# Dynamic function that prompt alert when i want to in a dynamic way

Tags: jquery, asp.net, function

This is the jQuery function that I want to fire it in my ASP. What I want is to make a dynamic function that's fired after I call it in my ASP code. It will take:

- id of the (div alert)
- alert type of div(example:alert alert-danger)
- the string in (`<a> string alert</a>`) to notify the user of mistakes

Moreover I create a var (counter) to prevent this function to be fired many times.

So the first time the function is fired it will increment (counter+=1). After that it will wait an amount of time (give the user permission to use the dismiss "close" behavior of bootstrap alert).

So if the user make the action "close" the `<div alert>` will be closed and the counter return to its initial value(0)

Can any expert help me please. Thank you.

```html
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtGroupName" CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="PromptAlert('txtGroupName_alert','alert alert-danger','this is alert string')" />
<div class="alert  alert-dismissible" id="txtGroupName_alert"></div>
```

```js
var $Counter = 0;

function PromptAlert(divID, alertType, alertString) {
  if ($Counter != 0) {
    this.preventDefault(); //prevent fire this function
  } else {
    $("#" + divID).prepend("<a id='thisA' href='#' data-dismiss='alert' aria-Label='close'>" + alertString + "</a>"); //add to div those elements
    $("#" + divID).addClass(alertType); //add the alert type written by programmer 
    $Counter += 1; //add the counter +1 to prevent the funvtion to fire many times 
    $("#" + divID).show(); //show the div alert
    $("#thisA").clik(function() {
      $(this).data('clicked', true)
    });
    if ($("#thisA").data('clicked') == true) //Check if it is clicked
    {
      $Counter = 0;
      $("#" + divID).hide(); //hide the alert div
    } else if ($("#thisA").data('clicked') == false) {
      $("#thisA").delay(12000).keypress(); //if keypress is not fired by the user before this delay fire it automatically
      $Counter = 0; // return the counter to 0 to prevent firing the same function many times 
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please take care to format your questions. Having everything in gigantic bold text is very off-putting and will mean you get fewer answers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan okay Dr.Rory thank you for managing my question in a proper way :)